# Should I use META viewport tag if using only desktop viewports?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, viewport

As title says, should I use `META viewport tag` if I'm using only **>991px** and **>1199px** media queries in `Bootstrap`?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: As an aside, have you thought about what happens if someone views your site on a smaller/larger device/resolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're building your website exclusively for desktop browsing (so no mobile site / responsive site), then no. The viewport tag is only there to tell mobile browsers that you've taken their smaller screens into account.

Good read on this subject:
http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho